# failed to open stream: Permission denied open server

Tags: php, html, database, file, upload

My aim is to download multiple files into the folder on my localhost. I am uploading them using the HTML form.

Here is the code (really sorry that I can't give a link to the executable version of the code because it relies on too many other files and database if anyone knows the way then please let me know)

```
foreach ($_FILES as $value) {
    $dir = '/';
    $filename = $dir.basename($value['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'],$filename)) {
        echo "File was uploaded";
        echo '<br>';
    }
    else {
        echo "Upload failed";
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

So this little piece of code give me an error:
[image]

And here are the lines of code:

The problem is that the adress is correct, I tried enterring it into my file directory and it worked fine, I have seen some adviced on other people's related questions that // or \ should be used instead, but my version works just fine! Also I have checked what's inside the $_FILES and here it is if that's required for someone trying to help:

[image]

Thank you very much if anyone could help!!

Comment: We dont need a picture of code ever, but definitely not when you have posted the code as text anyway

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to move the file to an invalid (or non-existent) path.
For the test you will write

```
 $dir = 'c:/existing_dir/';
 $filename = $dir.basename($value['name']);
```

If you want to move the file to a folder that is relative to the running file try

```
 $dir = '../../directory/';// '../' -> one directory back
 $filename = $dir.basename($value['name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

By starting your file path with `$dir = '/';` you are saying store the file on the root folder, I assume of `C:`

Apache if correctly configures should not allow you access to `C:\`

So either do

```
$dir = '../';
$filename = $dir.basename($value['name']);
```

to make it a relative path or leave the `$dir = '/';` out completely